# My custom object holding a list of another custom object

Tags: custom-object, list, fields, array

Maybe I am not understanding how salesforce works but I am trying to link up my custom object named "Program" to hold an array (or list) of another custom object I have called "Student". The structure I am trying to set up is to have my program hold a bunch of students. Maybe doing this through objects isn't the best way but I don't how else to set up this type of relationship. I'm importing the program and student information through csv.
I've googled around and saw that people just make a junction object and connect the two objects together that way but I fail to see how that would get you to connect an object to multiple objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Salesforce you would not really want to hold the values for another object in an array, you would normally use a Lookup or Master Detail relationship. [Considerations for relationships](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm). [Custom object relationships overview.](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=overview_of_custom_object_relationships.htm&language=en_US)

If you need there to be a junction object because the Students and Programs have a many to many relationship then that junction object would have 2 Master-Detail or Lookup relationships, 1 to Student and 1 to Program. The junction object can also be used to store attributes of the relationship, e.g. enrollment date, status, etc.

Comment: So it combines what fields both those objects have in common?
how you add records or connect records with the junction object?

Comment: nvm I figured it out I think